# Micro SD cards work on phone with Android 8 but corrupted in phone with Android 11?

Tags: sd-card, file-system, android-11, formatting

I have two SanDisk micro SD cards, a 8GB one for storing my photos and files in a Sony Xperia XA1, which runs Android 8.0 as the OS, the other one is a 128GB used in a Sony Xperia L3 phone, running Android 8.1. Since both of them had problems after years of usage, I bought a new phone, which is a Motorola e40, which runs Android 11.

When I transferred the micro SD card to the Motorola e40, it said the micro SD card is corrupted and asked for re-formatting. It happened to both of the micro SD cards. But the cards were actually working when I put them back to the Sony phones.

I wonder if the problem is on the OS. Does Android 11 use a micro SD card with a file system format different from that used by Android 8? Or is it the problem of the different phone brands?

I recall that both cards had not been formatted by me before when I used them for the Sony phones, so they should be pre-formatted by the manufacturer.

Also, the Motorola phone asked whether I would like to format the card as internal or portable storage (I did not choose either of them because the cards actually can work in the Sony phones and they contain data). But this option never appeared in my old Sony phones. So is it a property of the phone or Android 11?

Answer (score 0):

Is your SD card encrypted? I'm going to assume it's not, but there may be an update you can install that fixes the problem. If the device is different, use the device the SD card works on and copy all the files to your computer as a backup, usually this is a sign that your phone's SD reader is corrupted or going bad, either that or it's the SD card. Hearing you have two different devices, I will go with my chance and say the problem is with the SD card, prepare a backup while you can.